# How to make the full image appear at left side of division style

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to place a small image at left side of division style?

Example:

[image]

The code below doesn't work,what should I add to make the image appear at the left side of div tag

```
<div style="text-align:center;background-color: white; padding: 10px;background-image:url('https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/image8-2.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%">GOOGLE</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the first section, titled "Search... and research". You've [not shown any evidence of research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Answer (score 0):

What you have done right now is that you have set the background of the div to that image.
The example you provide too, I don't get it. The example is just an image.
If you want do what you saying
You can do this and see if that What you're talking about

```
<div style="width:auto; height:auto;"><img src="https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/image8-2.jpg" style="float:left; height:100px; width:100px;"/> <div style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:200px float:left"</div></div>
```

Comment: I meant a small  image will appear left side of of div tag like that leaf in the image

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my answer and you can copy and try to see if I've solved your problem

Comment: By the way, the example you provided is a very bad example. The example is a full image meanwhile you want something different. The leaf is part of the background

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VRG4.png it didn't work the image is too big

Comment: Show me the code. Maybe you did mistake, because I can see HTML code on the page which is not supposed to show of you typed well.